# A Thread-Safe FIFO in C99

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, pthreads, c99

I started a little weekend project to try and learn how to multithread with pure C99 and POSIX threads. The project is composed of three threads, input, processing, and output, which communicate with one another through FIFO queues. Namely we have `IN->FIFO->PROC->FIFO->OUT`. I just got the FIFO implementation to work, being thread safe, and I really wanted some feedback on what is good/bad and what can be improved.

**fifo.h**

```
#ifndef INC_05_ENC_DEC_FIFO_H
#define INC_05_ENC_DEC_FIFO_H
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>

struct list_node {
    struct list_node *prev;
    struct list_node *next;
    uint8_t *data;
};

typedef struct FIFO {
    struct list_node *first;
    struct list_node *last;

    size_t count;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;

    size_t (*count_mutex)(struct FIFO*);
    void (*enqueue)(struct FIFO*, uint8_t*);
    uint8_t* (*dequeue)(struct FIFO*);
    void (*free)(struct FIFO**, bool);
} fifo_t;

struct thread_bus {
    fifo_t *input;
    fifo_t *output;
    bool kill;
};

fifo_t *fifo_init();
void fifo_enqueue(fifo_t *queue, uint8_t *data);
uint8_t *fifo_dequeue(fifo_t *queue);
void fifo_free(fifo_t **queue, bool free_data);
size_t fifo_count(fifo_t *queue);

#endif //INC_05_ENC_DEC_FIFO_H
```

**fifo.c**

```
#include "fifo.h"

/*
 * Initializes a FIFO queue
 */
fifo_t *fifo_init() {
    fifo_t *queue = calloc(1, sizeof(fifo_t)); // Allocate struct
    queue->last = NULL;
    queue->first = NULL;
    queue->mutex = calloc(1, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)); // Allocate mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(queue->mutex, NULL); // Initialize the mutex, no attributes needed
    queue->count = 0; // To allow for O(1) counting

    // Function pointers
    queue->count_mutex = fifo_count;
    queue->enqueue = fifo_enqueue;
    queue->dequeue = fifo_dequeue;
    queue->free = fifo_free;

    return queue;
}

/*
 * Enqueues into FIFO
 */
void fifo_enqueue(fifo_t *queue, uint8_t *data) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(queue->mutex); // Lock
    // Allocate the node
    struct list_node *new = calloc(1, sizeof(struct list_node));
    new->data = data; // Link data

    // If we are enqueuing on an empty list, set first and last to be the singleton node
    if (queue->first == NULL) {
        queue->first = queue->last = new;
        ++queue->count;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex);
        return;
    }

    // Attach node
    queue->last->next = new;
    new->prev = queue->last;

    queue->last = new;
    ++queue->count; // Increment element count

    pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex); // Unlock
}

/*
 * Dequeue from FIFO
 */
uint8_t *fifo_dequeue(fifo_t *queue) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(queue->mutex); // Lock
    // Dequeueing on an empty FIFO returns NULL
    if (queue->first == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Detach node
    struct list_node *first = queue->first;
    queue->first = first->next;
    first->prev = NULL;

    // Save data pointer, free node
    uint8_t *data = first->data;
    free(first);

    --queue->count; // Decrement element count
    pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex); // Unlock

    return data;
}

/*
 * Free FIFO
 */
void fifo_free(fifo_t **queue, bool free_data) {
    pthread_mutex_lock((*queue)->mutex); // Lock

    // Iterate over FIFO, freeing nodes
    struct list_node *index;
    while ((index = (*queue)->first) != NULL) {
        (*queue)->first = (*queue)->first->next;
        // Optional data freeing
        if (free_data) {
            free(index->data);
            index->data = NULL;
        }
        free(index);
    }
    // Clean mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock((*queue)->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(((*queue)->mutex));
    free((*queue)->mutex);
    // Free structure
    free(*queue);
    *queue = NULL;
}

size_t fifo_count(fifo_t *queue) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(queue->mutex); // Lock
    size_t res = queue->count; // Save count
    pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex); // Unlock
    return res;
}

size_t fifo_debug_count(fifo_t *queue) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(queue->mutex); // Lock
    size_t count = 0;
    struct list_node *index = queue->first;
    while (index != NULL) {
        ++count;
        index = index->prev;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This post is quite old but I find it very relevant, since I am just trying to gain some understanding in the field of thread safety.

The provided example is probably correct and as I understand the issue is also thread safe. For this the use of `pthread_mutex_` calls are enough.

However as it is a FIFO the correct use of `phtread_cond_` would make it more usable. Especially the `fifo_dequeue` function returns immediately if the FIFO is empty. Thus checking on it repeatedly will consume a lot of resources.

The correct behaviour should be to block on this call if the FIFO is empty.
[Here](https://grapeprogrammer.com/how-to-use-pthread-cond-wait/) is a description of how to use the `pthread_cond_wait` function  correctly, however in different situation.

And [here](https://github.com/fragglet/c-algorithms/blob/master/src/queue.c) is a simple implementation of a queue (more than a FIFO) in C.